# Clarifying what modifies atime and the impact the find command might have

Tags: linux, files, find, ls

So on a regular basis I clear out files from my server which have an atime +160 with a command such as: (technically to delete old files but avoid any file that might have been accessed recently)

```
 find /tmp/art -atime +160 -exec rm -f {} \;
```

However, for some reason today no files show up unless I do atime +10. It appears all my files somehow got the access time changed to earlier this month. I've recently read the find command itself if used like the following would modify the atime:

```
 find /tmp/art -atime +160 -exec ls -l {} \;
```

But from my experience running either command has never changed the atime before. I was going to use ctime but just found out it does not mean change time.

My questions are:

1. Is it just a fluke the find command is not modifying my -atime or was the information I read incorrect?
2. If the files are available via a webserver for a user to browse them, would them downloading the file modify the atime? Or is the atime only modified when accessed via terminal/ssh?

Comment: What are your mount options for the filesystem containing `/tmp`?

Comment: Not sure what you mean but the /tmp is not a separate partition/disk. For example it does not show up if I run df -h.

Comment: http://www.thefreedictionary.com/containing